# How to fix apt-get install --fix-missing in docker build?

Tags: apt, docker

I have a problem when trying to run docker build. This is the command I run:

```
docker build -t <name> .
```

The Dockerfile contains the following first lines:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing \
    sudo \
    git
```

When building it though, I get the following error messages:

```
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/ifupdown/ifupdown_0.8.10ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Aborting install.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install --fix-missing     sudo     git' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

It works fine on my friend's computer, but continues to crash on mine every time I try again. I am using docker version 18.03.1-ce and Ubuntu 16.04.4, everything is up-to-date, and I honestly have no idea at all what is going wrong...

Comment: Did you check internet connectivity and that name resolution works inside Docker (`docker run -i -t [your image]` and then inside `ping 8.8.8.8 && dig askubuntu.com`)?

Comment: sorry if I'm missing something, but I can't run the image if I can't build it (which is what I have the problem with)

Comment: right, my bad. However, you can simply test the commands in `ubuntu:xenial` in order to exclude some issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error which I solved by giving docker build parm `--no-cache` as in

```
docker build -t <name> --no-cache  .
```

then after this builds correctly you are free to remove parm `--no-cache` for subsequent builds to speed up the build

Answer (score 0):

Docker's [instructions say](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) to place the update and install on the same line.

I also found that I could only use a plain old "RUN" command and that "ONBUILD" caused problems.

Comment: How can this explain the inability to fetch?  Update and install on the same line is intended to keep the image size down.